# Why must this density function be greater than zero almost everywhere?

Tags: probability-theory

In Klenke's Probability book, in Example 8.31, he states

[image]

Why is it that $f(x)>0$ a.a.? There are several densities for which we have $f(x)=0$ outside a compact set... For example, we can see the densities of the Beta distribution as zero outside the $[0,1]$ interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 'almost everywhere' requires a reference measure. You are taking the reference measure as Lebesgue measure. But the author is taking $P_X$ as the reference measure . Since $P_X (\{x: f (x)=0\})=\int_{\{x: f (x)=0\}} f(x)dx=0$ it follows that $f>0$ almost everywhere w.r.t. $P_X$.

Comment: Hi Kavi, many thanks for the help.  By the way, $f_X^{-1}$ being the density of the absolutely continuous part of Lebesgue measure, means that $\lambda(A) = \int_{A}f_X^{-1} d P_{X}= \int_{A}f_X^{-1}\circ f_X dP = \int_A d P$ where in our situation $P=\lambda$, right?